# v-text-field type datetime-local not working equal in all browsers

Tags: vue.js

I have the following code for working with timestamp datas getting from db and displaying in the interface.  However type 'datetime-local' works in Firefox, but not in Chrome. How can I solve this problem?

```
<v-text-field
  :type="'datetime-local'"
  :id="index"
  :data-name="name"
  v-model="value"
  @input="isSaveEditEnabled = true"
  outlined 
  dense                      
/>
```

Comment: You can use `v-date-picker` and `v-time-picker` components which respect the locale provided as a prop.

Comment: Yes, but for type 'date' I used v-text-field and it worked everywhere, thsts why didnt want to change styles.

Comment: Well, Vuetify can't impact the browser vendors and how they implement the web standards.